# solve-func in Python-sympy is very slow for linear equation system

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy, symbolic-math

For example

```
from sympy import *

v11, v12, v21, v22 = symbols('v11, v12, v21, v22')
w11, w12, w21, w22 = symbols('w11, w12, w21, w22')
x11, x12, x21, x22 = symbols('x11, x12, x21, x22')
y11, y12, y21, y22 = symbols('y11, y12, y21, y22')
z11, z12, z21, z22 = symbols('z11, z12, z21, z22')

r11, r12, r21, r22 = symbols('r11, r12, r21, r22')

a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, \
a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18 = symbols('a1:19')

# want to solve
b1, b2 = symbols('b1, b2')

# system of equations
eqn1  = a1*v11  + a2*v12  - b1       # a1 = 1
eqn2  = a1*v21  + a2*v22  - a3
eqn3  = a3*r11  + a4*r12  - a2
eqn4  = a3*r21  + a4*r22  - a5
eqn5  = a5*w11  + a6*w12  - a4   
eqn6  = a5*w21  + a6*w22  - a7
eqn7  = a7*r11  + a8*r12  - a6
eqn8  = a7*r21  + a8*r22  - a9
eqn9  = a9*x11  + a10*x12 - a8
eqn10 = a9*x21  + a10*x22 - a11
eqn11 = a11*r11 + a12*r12 - a10
eqn12 = a11*r21 + a12*r22 - a13
eqn13 = a13*y11 + a14*y12 - a12
eqn14 = a13*y21 + a14*y22 - a15
eqn15 = a15*r11 + a16*r12 - a14
eqn16 = a15*r21 + a16*r22 - a17
eqn17 = a17*z11 + a18*z12 - a16      # a18 = 0
eqn18 = a17*z21 + a18*z22 - b2

print('begin')
result = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, eqn5, eqn6, eqn7, \
                eqn8, eqn9, eqn10, eqn11, eqn12, eqn13, \
                eqn14, eqn15, eqn16, eqn17, eqn18], \
               [a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, \
                a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, b1, b2], \
                simplify=False, rational=False, manual=True)

b1_ans = result[b1]
b2_ans = result[b2]
print(b1_ans)
```

to solve these equations need MATLAB only in seconds, but by using sympy I cannot get the result.

Is there any way to speed up the solver? If not can you recommend another way to solve system of equations using python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have many more symbols than equations you will have to eliminate those that you are not interested in. Presumably you want to eliminate `want = set(var('a1:19'))` given the constraints of `eqs = [Eq(a1, 1), Eq(a18, 0), eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, eqn5, eqn6, eqn7, eqn8, eqn9, eqn10, eqn11, eqn12, eqn13, eqn14, eqn15, eqn16, eqn17, eqn18]`.

After recursively eliminating those (solving for a variable that appears in only 1 equation then removing that variable from `want`, the following relationships are obtained:

```
# recursively eliminate equations that have only one symbol of interest
sol = {}
while 1:
  was = len(sol)
  for ix, i in enumerate(eqs):
    if len(i.free_symbols & want) == 1:
        new = solve(i, *want, dict=True)
        assert len(new) == 1  # only doing this for single-solution equations
        sol.update(new[0])  # store in known values
  if len(sol) == was:
    break
```

#### order of equations

```
0 a1 - 1
1 a18
2 a1*v11 + a2*v12 - b1
3 a1*v21 + a2*v22 - a3
4 -a2 + a3*r11 + a4*r12
5 a3*r21 + a4*r22 - a5
6 -a4 + a5*w11 + a6*w12
7 a5*w21 + a6*w22 - a7
8 -a6 + a7*r11 + a8*r12
9 a7*r21 + a8*r22 - a9
10 a10*x12 - a8 + a9*x11
11 a10*x22 - a11 + a9*x21
12 -a10 + a11*r11 + a12*r12
13 a11*r21 + a12*r22 - a13
14 -a12 + a13*y11 + a14*y12
15 a13*y21 + a14*y22 - a15
16 -a14 + a15*r11 + a16*r12
17 a15*r21 + a16*r22 - a17
18 -a16 + a17*z11 + a18*z12
19 a17*z21 + a18*z22 - b2
```

#### solutions

```
{a1: 1, a18: 0, a2: (-a1*v11 + b1)/v12, a3: a1*v21 + a2*v22, a4: (a2 - a3*r11)/r12, a5: a3*r21 + a4*r22, a6: (a4 - a5*w11)/w12, a7: a5*w21 + a6*w22, a8: (a6 - a7*r11)/r12, a9: a7*r21 + a8*r22, a10: (a8 - a9*x11)/x12, a11: a10*x22 + a9*x21, a12: (a10 - a11*r11)/r12, a13: a11*r21 + a12*r22, a14: (a12 - a13*y11)/y12, a15: a13*y21 + a14*y22, a16: (a14 - a15*r11)/r12, a17: a15*r21 + a16*r22}
```

#### equations not solved/used

```
{Eq(-a16 + a17*z11 + a18*z12, 0), Eq(a17*z21 + a18*z22 - b2, 0)}
```

The solution for `a2` can be re-arranged for `b1` and the 2nd equation in the unsolved set can be solved for `b2`.

```
>>> solve(Eq(a17*z21 + a18*z22 - b2, 0), b2, dict=True)
[{b2: a17*z21 + a18*z22}]
>>> solve(s1[0][a2],b1, dict=True)
[{b1: a1*v11}]
```

The remaining equation represents a condition which must be satisfied for there to be a solution: `Eq(-a16 + a17*z11 + a18*z12, 0)`.

It would be interesting to see what the result from MATLAB is.